# Renomear diretório e diretórios filhos

Tags: bash

Eu gostaria de saber como é feito um código em bash para renomear todos os arquivos de uma certa extensão e pastas que comecem com um nome expecifico.
O repositório que quero fazer  as alterações:

https://github.com/gnramos/CIC-APC

por exemplo:

1.in -> 01.in
1.out -> 01.out

3_Fluxo -> 03_Fluxo
4_Subalgoritmos -> 04_Subalgoritmos

São apenas esses 3 casos, arquivos com extensão .in, .out, e pastas e comecem com um número menor que 10, caso não seja menor que 10, o 0 não precisa ser adicionado.

Comment: No seu caso, o arquivo 1.in teria o novo nome de 01.in ?

Answer (score 0):

Acessando cada diretório, você pode renomear todos os arquivos dentro dele usando:

`rename 's/^/0/' *`, para uma específica extensão é só alterar o `*` como `rename 's/^/0/' *.in`

ou também:

`for file in $(ls); do mv $file 0${file}; done`